# FileLogRoute.php maximum size error

Tags: error-message

When saving a whole bunch of users through a plugin I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1835217 bytes) in /home/butpanel/public_html/cmgg/craft/app/etc/logging/FileLogRoute.php on line 59
```

The users are saved none the less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your php.ini file's [memory_limit](https://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) is set to 64M.  Bump it up to something higher like 128M or 256M.